# Get order data by product id Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orm

i want to get all data (order_id , Bill to Name , ship to Name , BaseGrandTotal , GrandTotal ,Status ) about order with the known of product ids

Here is the sample of my code

```
    $ids=array();
    foreach ($collection as $product) { 
        $ids[]=$product->getId();
    }
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('in' => $ids))
                ->load();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$productId = 12735;
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $productId))
    ->load();

$order_ids = $collection->getColumnValues('order_id');

foreach($order_ids as $order_id){
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);    
    echo $order->getId(); // order id
    echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname().' '.$order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname(); 
    echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname().' '.$order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname(); 
    echo $order->getBaseGrandTotal(); // BaseGrandTotal
    echo $order->getGrandTotal(); // GrandTotal
    echo $order->getStatus(); // Status
}
```

if you need still more information about order use the following code

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getData());
```

if you need still more information about order billing data use the following code

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getBillingAddress()->getData());
```

if you need still more information about order shipping data use the following code

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getData());
```

Comment: i have this is error Call to a member function `getName()` 
`$order->getBillingAddress()->getName();`
`

Comment: show your code...

Comment: `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('in' => $ids))
     ->load();
     var_dump($collection);
     die;
  $order_ids = $collection->getColumnValues('order_id');
               foreach ($order_ids  as $order){
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id); 
                        echo  $order->getBillingAddress()->getName(); 
               }

`

Comment: try using echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname().$order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: same problem 
 Call to a member function getFirstname()

Comment: just see using echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getBillingAddress()->getData()); what u getting plz tell me

Comment: Call to a member function getData()

Comment: okay thanx it`s working now